# No puedo mostrar la variable que quiero

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

pasa que tengo una lista de resultados generada por una consulta a la base de datos

```
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

  $id     = $reg["id"];
  $descri = utf8_encode($reg["descri"]);
  $precio = $reg["precio"];
  $marca  = utf8_encode($reg["nombre_m"]);
  $catego = utf8_encode($reg["nombre_c"]);
  $pais   = utf8_encode($reg["pais"]);
  $imagen = $reg["imagen"];

include "../2.inc/formu-compras.inc";

  }
```

y el tema es que quiero que al clickear en uno de esos resultados

```
<!---Aquí sería el include "../2.inc/formu-compras.inc";---->

<!---Por ejemplo clikear el div con id = 2 agarrar lo que contenga $imagen y mostrarlo----->
  <div id="filas-imagen-marca">
     <div id="2"><?php echo "<img title='Agrandar imagen' src='$imagen' width='100' height='100'>";
                     echo "<input id='3' type='hidden' value='$imagen'>";
                 ?></div>
     <div id="filas-marca"><?php echo "$marca"; ?></div>
  </div>
```

me permita ver la variable que lo compone (sin recargar la pagina). 
Lo intenté hacer aplicando ajax, pero solo me muestra el contenido del primer `$imagen` que sale, y quiero que me muestre dependiendo del que haya clickeado, pero no sé cómo. Les dejo lo que queda de mi código para que se hagan mejor la idea.

```
$(document).on('click','#2', function() {
 var imagenpop=$("#3").val();

 pop(imagenpop);
});

function pop(imagenpop){
$.ajax({
   url : 'popup.php',
     type : 'POST',
     datatype :'html',
   data : { imagenpop : imagenpop
     },
})

.done(function(resultado) {
    $("#popup_a").html(resultado);
})

}
```

Aquí lo que tengo en "popup.php"

```
if (isset($_POST['imagenpop'])) {
  $q=$_POST["imagenpop"];

  echo "$q";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sugiero que revises las fuentes donde estás aprendiendo jQuery, porque usas código obsoleto. Por ejemplo los `$(document).on(` hace ya tiempo que fueron declarados obsoletos, en su lugar debes usar `function` simplemente.

De hecho, este código no escucha a nadie realmente:

```
$(document).on('click','#2', function() {
```

Siempre es bueno verificar que el código hace el recorrido poniendo `console.log` o `alert` simplemente y una vez depurado el código los quitas.

La forma más simple que hay para escuchar los elementos es esta:

```
$("#2").click(function(e) {
```

Organizando tu código así debería funcionar:

```
/* 
    *Se recomienda function() en lugar de document.ready
    *ya que éste es obsoleto desde jQuery 3
*/
$( function() {     

    $("#2").click(function() {
         var imagenpop=$("#3").val();
         console.log(imagenpop); //A modo de prueba, borrar luego
         pop(imagenpop);
    });

});


function pop(imagenpop){
    console.log("..."+imagenpop); //Probando si llega aquí el dato
    $.ajax({
         url : 'popup.php',
         method : 'POST',  //type también es obsoleto
         datatype :'html',
         data : { imagenpop : imagenpop},
    })

    .done(function(resultado) {
        $("#popup_a").html(resultado);
    })

}
```

Comment: De hecho me sucede el mismo problema, me muestra la variable $imagen pero solo  la primera que genera el "while". La idea es que muestre el valor de esa variable dependiendo sobre cual haga click.